# What to do with unused water supply lines?

Tags: plumbing

I am remodeling my bathroom and installing a single vanity in place of a double vanity.  There are two sets of PEX water supply lines in the wall - can one of those sets be plugged?[image: image of one side attached - both sides identical]

Comment: You don't want un-swept legs in the plumbing system. Bacteria or other microorganisms could harbor there because (1) the chlorine level will drop in a dead leg and (2) there would be  no mechanical sweeping out of the pipe by flow

Comment: @JimStewart  really? Not sure how big of an issue this really is. I hope not too big since I capped off a similar set recently

Comment: Ask the plumbing inspectors about it. You are getting this inspected, right? Maybe I am perfectionist, but I think capping off a *short* dead leg might be OK, but I would not think that more than a few inches would be acceptable.

Comment: Based on what I have read since Jim's answer  I agree it's not a good idea.  I have a plumber coming out today to give me an estimate for removing the lines completely.  Thank you Jim :)

Comment: Quick update.  Plumber just left - he verified that it would be okay to plug off the unused supply lines based on my particular configuration.  Relieved to not have to cut out subfloor sections!  I do not regret calling him though, as I did read some pretty bad horror stories about un-swept legs and bacteria.  Would rather pay someone to do it right if it means my family doesn't get sick.

Comment: Glad to hear the plumber thinks you won't have to do more work than you want to. For my learning purposes, how long is the dead leg you are leaving? I assume this is teed off a line which has flow past the dead leg.  Instead of going down and removing the T, you could connect the now unused lines to the lines that flow into the single lavatory. This would be before the cutoff valve. There would be two parallel lines for hot and cold. I wouldn't  know if this would be allowed by code, but this would resolve the issue of unswept piping.

Comment: It is a teed off line that has flow past the leg.  The plumber did not say specifically how long the dead legs would be, but just said that they wouldn't be long enough to cause an issue - and even said it was exactly what he would do.  I am assuming they are just under the sub-floor a few inches down from that picture above.  I had the same thought of joining the two sets of lines, but read in a plumbing forum that doing that would cause a "hammering" issue from unequal pressure.  To be honest, that type of setup would make me way more comfortable if it was possible.